# Dynamically include script element in header or HTML by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a script to the third party JavaScript library which requires token to be injected dynamically.

I was told to include script below into the head of my html. I need to replace {your_token} in order for this to work. However this token is only available at runtime so I need to inject this script into the header of my application at runtime (init for the application code)

> `<script>(function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel={your_token}...`

What is the best way to replace your_token with right token and inject this script at the header of the application?

Comment: Do you mean inject a value in place for '{your_token}' from your view? Are you using templates on the server to construct your HTML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "this token is only available at runtime" means "from the `onModuleLoad`" (for whichever reason), then you could have the script as a `String` in your GWT app (you might want to use a `ClientBundle` with the script in a `TextResource`, or simply a `String` constant in your code), replace `{your_token}` with `String#replace` and then inject the resulting script with the `ScriptInjector.fromString`.

Though if you can, use "backend replacement" [as proposed by Mike Li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17635616/116472) with a [dynamic host page](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just as Casey asked, it depends on where this script block come from?

1. Backend replacement

   If you use any backend template engine, you probably have the opportunity to replace that token into the one you have in hand. So the output will be the script contains the real token the script needed.
2. Front end replacement

   If you are using some template in front such as using handlebar template(other template engines works almost the same) `<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">your third party js code <token here></script>`, you can replacing the token when generating the dom element.

For me I prefer do this at backend.